# Hiding Status Bar of UIPageViewController in Swift 3.0 iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller, uistatusbar

**Please Read the question before marking it as duplicate.**

I know there are a lot of questions regarding **Hiding Status Bar** of a `View Controller` in `iOS`. But none of them solves my problem.

I am using `Swift - 3.0`
Here is my scenario:

1. I am able to hide status bar on a single `UIViewController` using `prefersStatusBarHidden` computed property. So no problem with that.
2. I have a `UIPageViewController(DetailPageViewController)` that contains several `UIViewControllers(DetailViewController)` as child controllers. In each of those child view controllers, I have another `UIPageViewController(PhotosPageViewController)` which further contains multiple `UIViewControllers(PhotoViewController)`. i.e.,

**DetailPageViewController --> multiple DetailViewController**

**each DetailViewController --> PhotosPageViewController --> multiple PhotoViewController**

So, the problem is I am not able to hide status bar of all the 4 controllers -  `DetailPageViewController, DetailViewController, PhotosPageViewController, PhotoViewController`

Comment: I am not sure.but,you should be looking at `var childViewControllerForStatusBarHidden: UIViewController? { get }` to achieve this function.for more info https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621440-prefersstatusbarhidden

Comment: I tried this already..but no luck.

Comment: i wondering.how many VC does have statusBar in your project or only in mainVC?

Answer (score 0):

You can either hide Status Bar from storyboard for each view controller you are initialize just chose none for that mater

[image] 
   [image]

or you can create a BaseViewController and do it programmatically and subclass your controller from BaseViewController

```
BaseViewController: UIViewController {
    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
       return true
    }
}

DetailViewController: BaseViewController {
   // your codes goes here
}
```

Beware of that if you use this method it is only gonna work on controllers that is inherit from UIViewController and not UITableViewController or such,In that case you should create such file for them to if you have few of them.

Hope this will help